# IntelliJ 2019 scroll to source missing from project options menu

Tags: intellij-idea, menu, project

My question consist of 2 parts:

1. After update to 2019 version of IntelliJ Scroll to Source option from project panel is missing, after some web search I'm unable to find it. Is it missing? Default?
2. I'd like to set "scroll to source" so that whenever I'm opening tab it's highlighted in project, but exclude redirect to external libraries like java's or node_modules (they tend to be several classes long and make scrolling time-consuming). Excluding those libraries from project would be kind of a way perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions have been renamed improve an user experience for those who move from other IDEs: **Autoscroll to Source** -> **Open Files with Single Click**, **Autoscroll from Source** -> **Always Select Opened File**; see [IDEA-217044](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217044).

Note that **Scroll from Source** button (currently called **Select Opened File**) is only available if **Always Select Opened FIle** is disabled.

There is no way to disable auto-scrolling to libraries; please vote for [IDEA-200580](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200580) to be notified on any progress with this feature request.